# Testify mocking a single method

Tags: go, testing, mocking

I'm pretty new to go. I'm trying to mock a single method of a `struct` using `testify`, but I don't know how to do it.

Here's the code:

```
type HelloWorlder interface {
    SayHello() string
    GetName() string
}

type HelloWorld struct{}

func (hw *HelloWorld) SayHello() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Hello World from %s!", hw.GetName())
}

func (hw *HelloWorld) GetName() string {
    return "se7entyse7en"
}
```

and here's the test:

```
type MockHelloWorld struct {
    mock.Mock
    HelloWorld
}

func (m *MockHelloWorld) GetName() string {
    args := m.Called()
    return args.String(0)
}

type SomeTestSuite struct {
    suite.Suite
}

func (s *SomeTestSuite) TestMocking() {
    mhw := new(MockHelloWorld)
    mhw.On("GetName").Return("foo bar")

    fmt.Println(mhw.SayHello())
}
```

The idea is to mock only the `GetName` method so that it prints `Hello World from foo bar!`. Is that possible?

For those familiar with Python, what I'm trying to achieve is similar to what the [`unittest.Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) class permits through the `wraps` argument.

**UPDATE**
The imported packages from `testify` are these:

```
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/suite"
```

Comment: specify witch `testify` package you are talking about. Or you can see example on https://github.com/stretchr/testify#mock-package.

Comment: I already saw the examples and I also successfully mocked a struct, but only when all methods are mocked. What I want to do know is to mock only a single method that is called by another one that I don't want to mock.

Comment: Suppose you have one function `Calculation(obj SomeObj)`, SomeObj is interface with 3 methods. So you want to make a mocked SomeMockObj,but implemented only one method. Then you wanted to call `Calculation(someMockObj)`?

Comment: Exactly. Let's say that the interface `SomeObj` has methods `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz`. And that a `struct` that implements this interface has the method `Foo` that does something with the output of the method `Bar`. Given that I want to test the method `Foo` depending on the output of `Bar` I want to create a mocked `SomeMockObj` that doesn't change the original behaviour of `Foo`, but only the one of `Bar` by using something like `mockedObj.On("Bar").Return("bar output")`.

Comment: Go likes `interface{}`. You can define `BarInterface{}` with method `Bar`， then `struct` implements `Foo` that does something with the result of `BarInterface`'s `Bar`. After that ,you can mock `Bar` with a `mockedObj ` implement `BarInterface` to test you real `struct`

Comment: Aren't two separated struct one wrapping another by doing as you said? Can you provide a working snippet?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

type userReader interface {
    ReadUserInfo(int) int
}

type userWriter interface {
    WriteUserInfo(int)
}

type UserRepository struct {
    userReader
    userWriter
}

type realRW struct{}

func (db *realRW) ReadUserInfo(i int) int {
    return i
}

func (db *realRW) WriteUserInfo(i int) {
    fmt.Printf("put %d to db.\n", i)
}

// this is mocked struct for test writer.
type MyMockedWriter struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *MyMockedWriter) ReadUserInfo(i int) int {

    args := m.Called(i)
    return args.Int(0)

}

func main() {
    rw := &realRW{}
    repo := UserRepository{
        userReader: rw,
        userWriter: rw,
    }
    fmt.Println("Userinfo is:", repo.ReadUserInfo(100))
    repo.WriteUserInfo(100)

    // when you want to write test.
    fmt.Println("Begin test....................")
    testObj := new(MyMockedWriter)
    testObj.On("ReadUserInfo", 123).Return(250)

    testRepo := UserRepository{
        userReader: testObj,
        userWriter: rw,
    }
    fmt.Println("Userinfo is:", testRepo.ReadUserInfo(123))
    testRepo.WriteUserInfo(100)
}

// Output:
// Userinfo is: 100
// put 100 to db.
// Begin test....................
// Userinfo is: 250
// put 100 to db.
```

Good luck.